# uninitialized constant when including validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have the following file `/app/validators/hex_color.rb` in my Rails app:

```
module Validators
  class HexColorValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      unless value =~ /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/i
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'must be a valid CSS hex color code')
      end
    end

  end
end
```

And then in my model at : `/app/models/brand_theme.rb` I have:

```
class BrandTheme < ApplicationRecord

  include Validators

  validates :brand_1, presence: true, hex_color: true

end
```

But I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant BrandTheme::Validators
```

Why isn't the validator being included? I have tried resetting server as well but the same issue comes up.

Comment: You probably didn't add `app/validators` to `autoload_paths`.

Comment: @MarekLipka I was under the impression everything under `app` is auto-loaded in Rails? We have several other folders under there that are auto-loaded just fine.

Comment: Well, it isn't. You have to do it manually.

Comment: If that's the case how come I can do `/app/random/something.rb` and it loads up automatically?

Comment: @Cameron You are right. It's really autoloaded. Watch my answer

Comment: Ok, I was wrong and autoload does work like you expected. So I think there's namespacing issue here - rails probably expect `validators.rb` file somewhere in autoload directories and it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not getting loaded, because you don't follow rails convention. You shouldn't put it to the Validations module. And I would go with module HexColor... not the class.

So here is the solution... File `/app/validators/hex_color_validator.rb`:

```
module HexColorValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'must be a valid CSS hex color code')
    end
  end
end

class BrandTheme < ApplicationRecord
  include HexColorValidator

  validates :brand_1, presence: true, hex_color: true
end
```

Then it will be autoloaded. If you want to require several modules, then go with module as a subfolder of `app/validators` or just include several separate modules

Comment: While you use validate_each... maybe you will need to go with `extend HexColorValidator`